# sql join issue, not able to retrieve records from table a which matches some condition in table b and remaining left out table a records

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatables

I am writing a sql query to get all those records from table A which matches table b with certain condition, and all left out records from table a , which are not there in table b. Below is the code and tables

Table A

```
skey    OrderName    
100     Pen     
100     Cutter  
101     any
```

Table b

```
skey    OrderName   Key
100     Pen        True
100     Cutter      



select a.skey,a.orderName
from Test_A a
     left join Test_B b
     on a.skey=b.skey
where b.kit='True' and a.orderName=b.orderName
```

Result I need is

```
skey   Ordername  
100       Pen (Because this is true in table B)
101       any
```

Comment: Please learn to tag your question properly.  MySQL and Oracle are two completely different product.  Which one is this???

Answer (score 1):

Here is the idea:

```
select a.skey, a.orderName
from Test_A a left join
     Test_B b
     on a.skey = b.skey and
        a.orderName = b.orderName 
where b.kit = 'True' or   -- matches and value is true
      b.skey is null.     -- no match
```

Comment: Thanks for answer . But the thing is if table b has 2 values and none of that is having key as true, then I need both the values in result . Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
select a.skey,a.orderName from Test_A a
left join Test_B b
on a.skey=b.skey  and a.orderName=b.orderName
where b.kit='True' and b.skey is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM Test_A a LEFT JOIN Test_B b
ON b.skey = a.skey AND b.OrderName = a.OrderName 
WHERE b.kit = 'True'
   OR (b.kit IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Test_B WHERE skey = a.skey AND kit = 'True'))
```

Or without a join:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM Test_A a 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Test_B b WHERE b.skey = a.skey AND b.OrderName = a.OrderName AND b.kit = 'True') 
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Test_B b WHERE b.skey = a.skey AND b.kit = 'True')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=831751678a3ecebf2b4a96804e64c191).
Results:

```
> skey | OrderName
> ---: | :--------
>  100 | Pen      
>  101 | any
```